# Have Firefox recognise user.js as a 0 size symlink

Tags: windows, firefox, symbolic-link

With reference to this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=528954), how can I have Firefox recognise user.js as a 0 size symlink? This [comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=528954#c3) appears to offer some guidance, but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: This is a 7 year old bug report that was resolved as fixed in the development builds. What is your real problem?

Comment: The bug is still present in the latest release version: user.js, created as a symlink, is ignored because it has a 0 size.

Comment: Is there a way that I can change the size of the symlink so that it appears to Firefox to be a non-empty file?